# Nested fragments UML understanding?

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I have a UML book and I am reading about nested fragments. It shows an example of a nested fragment. But what I dont get.. why does it say "If the condition "cancelation not sucessful" is true when entering this fragment (i.e. cancelation was unsuccesful) the interaction within this fragment is no longer executed".

What I have learned before is that a condition should be true before the interaction will be executed? But in this case it says the opposite of it.. (because they say it should be false to execute the interaction)

See for the image: https://ibb.co/CmstLcX

Answer (score 3):

I think this is simply a typo in the book. The diagram makes sense, but the text describes nonsense. While the condition is true, the messages in the loop will happen up to three times.

Maybe the author got confused, because the message immediately before the loop is `Cancellation`. I assume the loop guard is referring to the success of the `Order cancellation` message, not to this `Cancellation`.

By the way, reply messages need to have the name of the original message. Most people get this wrong (and some textbooks). I'll grant that the text on the reply message is often meant to be the return value. As such it should be separated with a colon from the name of the message. In your case it is probably not necessary to repeat the message name, even though techically required. However, the colon is mandatory.

If it is the return value, all reply messages in the loops return the value `Acceptance`. I wonder, how the guard can then evaluate to true after the first time. Maybe it is only showing the scenario for this case. This is perfectly Ok. A sequence diagram almost never shows all possible scenarios. However, then the loop doesn't make sense. I guess the author didn't mean to return a specific value.

Or maybe it is the assignment target. In this case, it should look like this: `Acceptance=Order Cancellation`. Then the `Acceptance` attribute of the `Dispatcher Workstation` would be filled with whatever gets returned by the `Order Cancellation` message. Of course, then I would expect this attribute to be used in the guard, like this `[not Acceptance]`.

A third possiblity is, that the author didn't mean synchroneous communication and just wanted to send signals. The Acceptance Signal could well contain an attribute `Cancellation not successful`. Then of course, no filled arrows and no dashed lines.

I can even think of a fourth possibility. Maybe the author wanted to show the name of an out parameter of the called operation. But this would officially look like this: `Order Cancellation(Acceptance)`. Again the name of the message could be omitted, but the round brackets are needed to make the intention clear.

I think the diagram leaves a lot more questions open than you asked.

Comment: Yes. Probably the answer is: wrong book.

Comment: Good answer. It would be even better if you would remove everything pertaining to the reply message, because that was not OP's issue.

Answer (score 1):

It only says "If the cancellation was not successful then" (do exception handling). This is pretty straight forward. `if not false` is the same as `if true`. Since it is within a `Break` fragment, this will be performed (with what ever is inside) and as a result will break the fragment where it is contained (usually some loop). Having a break just stand alone seems a bit odd (not to say wrong).

UML 2.5 p. 581:

> **17.6.3.9 Break**
>
> The interactionOperator break designates that the CombinedFragment represents a breaking scenario in the sense that the operand is a scenario that is performed instead of the remainder of the enclosing InteractionFragment. A break operator with a guard is chosen when the guard is true and the rest of the enclosing Interaction Fragment is ignored. When the guard of the break operand is false, the break operand is ignored and the rest of the enclosing InteractionFragment is chosen. The choice between a break operand without a guard and the rest of the enclosing InteractionFragment is done non-deterministically.
>
> A CombinedFragment with interactionOperator break should cover all Lifelines of the enclosing InteractionFragment.

Except for that: you should not take fragments too serious. Graphical programming is nonsense. You make only spare use of any such constructs and only if they help understanding certain behavior. Do *not* get tempted to re-document existing code this way. Code is much more dense and better to read. YMMV

Comment: Maybe I don't get it.. but the sentence is:
" If the cancellation was not successfull"  is 'TRUE'  (so I see this as the condition of the LOOP fragment is triggered because the condition is met. But the book says..
" The interaction within the repetition fragment is no longer executed" . Where I think.. why not? Because the condition is true.. so it should execute?

Comment: That's because it's a `break` fragment. it will break the outer (loop) fragment.

Comment: There is no outer loop fragment. The break fragment is on the highest level and breaks the whole Interaction. An Interaction _is an_  InteractionFragment, and therefore the text you cited here applies to the whole Interaction as well.

Comment: @AxelScheithauer Oh, I missed your comment. It's probably more like "graphical programming is not the way to go". I use fragments in my SDs only in rare cases and as simple as possible. It's really not easy to place them long with the messages - I'm using EA :-( In the early 80s I thought about using a plotter for documenting code. It was a fail (of course). Ever since I'm suspicious when it comes to things like that.